# serial data from avr to python

Tags: avr, serial, rs232, attiny

I am using ATtiny2313 microcontroller along with a RS232 to establish communication between my microcontroller and the laptop. 
Here's my question : 
What is the predefined system for the laptop to make sense of the data that i send using the microcontroller ? (i.e. what is the number of parity bits, start bits... that the laptop expects to make sense of the data ?)

I tried reading the data using python but all data reads 0xff
my avr code sends a constant byte 0x01010101 every one seconds and laptop detects every new byte every 1 second. But every byte is sensed as 0xff. 
What could be the problem ?
(i am using the screen function in the mac terminal to view the RS232 data).

Please help

Comment: Is baud rate same on both sides?

Comment: @Swanand YES ! the baud rate is 9600 on both the sides. I also checked it using a DSO

Comment: Baud rate, Parity, Start Bit, Stop Bit settings can be anything but both should be same on Computer and Microcontroller. Set Handshaking to OFF on Computer (if you are not planning to use RTS-CTS lines)

Comment: @Swanand i crosschecked everything. Still reading 0xff only

Comment: Can you check on any other terminal application? If that is receiving data correctly, then it is issue with your Python code... If it is also receiving 0xFF, then issue with Configuration

Comment: @Swanand i tried connecting the tx pin of the microcontroller to the rx pin of arduino and then view the data on serial monitor. The bytes are not recognized (question mark symbols seen)

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Post a diagram of your setup. You don't mention an arduino in your question, but your last comment mentions arduino.

Answer (score 1):

make sure that the baud rate, number of parity bits, start bits and stop bits  are same in your microcontroller and in your serial terminal program. In every serial terminal applications there are options to set the number of parity bits, start bits e.t.c. So the terminal program expects data in the format which is defined by the you. Install any other serial terminal application and check to see the correct byte is received. If the correct bit is received then it may be the problem with your python program.